# Where Linux socket API can be found when invoked by JVM?

Tags: c++, jvm

I tried to find the Linux socket API for reading the network stream from the JVM, however I blocked at the following code, as I have no idea how to continue checking the ::recv, as I don't know which class declare\implement it, as it has no class name in front of it.

```
int os::recv(int fd, char *buf, int nBytes, int flags) {
  INTERRUPTIBLE_RETURN_INT(::recv(fd, buf, nBytes, flags), os::Solaris::clear_interrupted);
}

at file openjdk-7-fcs-src-b147-27_jun_2011\openjdk\hotspot\src\os\solaris\vm\os_solaris.cpp
```

My question is how to get the declare\implementation for the ::recv and where we can find the Linux socket API for reading the network stream invoked by the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::recv()` is a system call provided by the operating system. There is no further you can go along this path.

Comment: If the ::recv() exists in the following Linux source code, such as version 4.8? If it is can you kindly help to figure it out.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/

Comment: You're kidding, right? Help you to 'figure out' an API that relies on TCP, UDP, raw sockets, Unix-domain sockets, ...? The textbook you need is Stevens & Wright, *TCP/IP Illustrated,* volumes I and II, and these are about six inches thick. You can't learn this stuff on StackOverflow.

Comment: JVM calls  ::recv() , I just want to know which function in the Linux related to the  ::recv() .

Comment: And the answer is whatever code implements the system call `recv()`. It is *not* going to do you any good to delve further. All you need to know is what it says in the documentation, that it blocks until at least one byte arrives or an error occurs, and in the no-error cse transfers whatever bytes have arrived. It would be more to the point for you to post whatever *actual problem* you are trying to solve.

Comment: I got the errno ECONNRESET ,  just I described in the following URL .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969948/linux-kernel-for-dealing-with-connection-reset-from-peer-machine. i know this caused by the connection peer reset  the connection, however what I need to know is how Linux kernel deal with the reset at the kernel source code level .

Comment: And the answer to that is *why* did you get ECONNRESET, and the way to find out is not to read Stevens & Wright vols I & II or the entire Linux kernel but to ask a better question, including *what you were doing at the time.* You're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Yes, maybe my title is not so good, i just study the Linux kernel for the network part for how the kernel deal with the network input stream.

Comment: Have you got a year for that? or are you trying to implement something now?